# SolrCloud loading Synonym file from resouce

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am trying to setup a test SolrCloud 4.5.1 implementation. My synonym file is about 1.6 MB. When I try to add collection to ZooKeeper 3.4.5 on Ubuntu 12.4, it fails because of the 1MB limit of ZooKeeper. Has anyone any experience with using such synonym files? Can I store them in some other location other than the Config Folder since the config folder is loaded into ZooKeeper

TIA

Answer (score 2):

Asked long time ago but here is the answer. Yes you can. As Fallback the ZkSolrResourceLoader fetches files from the classpath, so simply add the file to the classpath by putting it in the resources or lib folder.

Comment: old but gold. I placed this 4.4MB synonyms file inside our custom tokenizer jar file in solr lib and it works like a charm.